# How do I fix my cmake configuration which creates a library that uses PRIVATE include_directories

Tags: cmake

I am learning how to write "modern" cmake configurations and am trying to create link a library to an executable. My test project structure looks as follows:

```
.
|-- foo
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- foo.cpp
|   |   `-- foo_impl.cpp
|   |-- include
|   |   `-- foo
|   |       `-- foo.h
|   |-- internal
|   |   `-- foo_impl.h
|   `-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- src
|   `-- main.cpp
`-- CMakeLists.txt
```

./CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(test_cmake LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(foo)
add_executable(test_executable
  src/main.cpp
  )

target_include_directories(test_executable
  PRIVATE
    include
    foo
  )
```

./foo/CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

add_library(foo
  src/foo_impl.cpp
  src/foo.cpp
  )

target_include_directories(foo
  PUBLIC
    include
  PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  )
```

The reasoning for this configuration is to test if cmake exposes the "foo/internal" folder to clients of the library foo.

1. Having difficulty linking with the library foo.
2. Unable to use #include "foo/foo.h" in client code.

Have I made a mistake in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type/error in your cmake.

In CMakeLists.txt you do:

```
target_include_directories(test_executable
```

This will add include directories. You need to link with `foo` project:

```
target_link_libraries(test_executable
    PRIVATE foo)
```